# Creating a header column via "for" loop in a multiplication table produces gibberish instead of desired result

Tags: c++, formatting, multiplication

I need to create a multiplication table of a number between 1 and 20, I've did just that using 2 nested for loops. What I'm having problems with is the formatting of the table - the output in the console needs to look exactly like your average multiplication table in a schoolbook, horizontal and vertical row of numbers and when you find the cross between the horizontal and the vertical numbers you find your multiplication. I've done the horizontal row using a "first pass" check as you can see in the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()

{

    int br;
    int firstpass = 1;

    cin >> br;

    if (br > 1 && br < 21)

    {
        if (firstpass = 1)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h <= br; h++)
                cout << setw(5) << h << " ";

            cout << endl;
            firstpass = 0;
        }

        for (int a = 1; a <= br; a++)

        {


            for (int b = 1; b <= br; b++)
                    cout << setw(5) << a * b << " ";
            cout << endl;

        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

but the problem with the code above is that it doesn't produce a vertical column (in front of each output in the nested loop should be the number of a), so I added a "second pass" check. The goal was to check if it's a start of a new row via "secondpass", if it is, output the current value of "a" then lie dormant until the loop ends and secondpass is reset, but instead of just adding the value of "a" at the start of the row and then outputting the rest of the row like the first example does, it's showing pure gibberish that I can't untangle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()

{

    int br;
    int firstpass = 1;
    int secondpass = 1;

    cin >> br;

    if (br > 1 && br < 21)

    {
        if (firstpass = 1)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h <= br; h++)
                cout << setw(5) << h;

            cout << endl;
            firstpass = 0;
        }

        for (int a = 1; a <= br; a++)

        {


            for (int b = 1; b <= br; b++)

            {

                if (secondpass = 1)
                {
                    cout << setw(5) << a;
                    secondpass = 0;
                }
                cout << setw(5) << a << a * b;

            }

            secondpass = 1;
            cout << endl;


        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure this fever I'm under isn't exactly helping but I'm feeling really dumb right now. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please create an answer. The comments formatting has failed you.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()

{

    int br;

    cin >> br;

    if (br > 1 && br < 21)

    {

        for (int a = 0; a <= br; a++)

        {

            for (int b = 0; b <= br; b++)

            {
                if (b == 0)
                    cout << setw(5) << a;
                else if (a == 0)
                    cout << setw(5) << b;
                else
                    cout << setw(5) << a * b;
            }

            cout << endl;

        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Here's the answer for someone down the line, finally cracked it. Still no idea why the nested for loops were acting spooky when trying to add another character the original way I did but I guess that's a question for another time.